# i'm doing a project for class and i can't understand why the last line is being flaged as unindented?

Tags: python

This is a class thing im doing and in the last line when i run my program it says unexpected unindent. I cant understand. Help.

```
b = 0
maxpass = 68
minpass = 0
fn = "FNO123"
amount = 0
seatsremain = 68 - b

print ("Welcome to Flight Booking Program")

print ("Please enter the flight number you want to book/cancel with? (Case Sensitve)")
flight = input()

while flight != "X":
    seatsremain = 68 - b
    while True:
        if b >= minpass and b <= maxpass:
            break
        else:
            print ("Sorry but the flight you want is currently fully booked. Sorry for Inconviniance")

    if flight == fn:
        print ("There are currently", seatsremain, "seats remaining")
        print ("Would you like to book or cancel your flight?")
        booking = input().lower()
    else:
        print ("ERROR")
        print ("Not a valid flight number! Remember input is CASE SENSITIVE")
        print ("Welcome to Flight Booking Program")
        print ("Please enter the flight number you want to book/cancel with? (Case Sensitve)")
        flight = input()

        while True:
            if booking == "c" or booking == "cancel" or booking == "b" or booking == "book":
                break
            else:
                print ("ERROR")
                print ("You must cancel at least 1 seat and not exceed the minimum amount of seats avaliable")
                print ("There are currently", seatsremain, "seats remaining")
                print ("Would you like to book or cancel your flight?")

        if booking == "b" or booking == "book":
            print ("How many seats are you booking?")
            while True:
                try:
                    amount = int(input())

                    if amount <1 or amount >seatsremain:
                        print ("ERROR")
                        print ("You must book at least 1 seat and not exceed the maximum amount of seats avaliable")
                        print ("There are currently", seatsremain, "seats remaining")
                        print ("Would you like to book or cancel your flight?")
                    else:
                        b = b + amount
                        print ("Your flight has been Booked!")
                        print ("Welcome to Flight Booking Program")
                        print ("Please enter the flight number you want to book/cancel with? (Case Sensitve)")
                        flight = input()
                        break
                except ValueError:
                    print ("You must enter a valid number!")

        elif booking == "c" or "cancel":
            print ("How many seats are you canceling?")
            while True:
                try:
                    amount = int(input())

                    if amount <1 or amount >b:
                        print ("ERROR")
                        print ("You must cancel at least 1 seat and not exceed the minimum amount of seats avaliable")
                        print ("There are currently", seatsremain, "seats remaining")
                        print ("Would you like to book or cancel your flight?")
                    else:
                        b = b - amount
                        print ("Your flight has been Cancelled!")
                        print ("Welcome to Flight Booking Program")
                        print ("Please enter the flight number you want to book/cancel with? (Case Sensitve)")
                        flight = input()
                        break


print("There are", b, "people booked on flight", fn)
```

Comment: Please don't add gibberish to overcome the limits. If your post is not meeting the requirements then there certainly is an issue with your post. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Just for the style... The `print` is a function. This way you should write `print(something)` and not `print (something)` (with space after print).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second 'try' doesn't have an 'except'. Because this is missing your final line is unexpectedly unindented. Python is trying to find something indented equal to the try statement since 'except' is required.

```
while True:
    try:
        amount = int(input())

        if amount <1 or amount >b:
            print ("ERROR")
            print ("You must cancel at least 1 seat and not exceed the minimum amount of seats avaliable")
            print ("There are currently", seatsremain, "seats remaining")
            print ("Would you like to book or cancel your flight?")
        else:
            b = b - amount
            print ("Your flight has been Cancelled!")
            print ("Welcome to Flight Booking Program")
            print ("Please enter the flight number you want to book/cancel with? (Case Sensitve)")
            flight = input()
            break
    except ValueError: #<- Add something like this
        print ("You must enter a valid number!")
```